# How do we achieve this Material Design UI?

Tags: android, material-design

Material design provide a beautiful style, but how do we create UI like the link below in android?

- A header container
- A floating circle button
- A listview

Any code samples in Github or somewhere?

http://www.materialpalette.com/purple/cyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look into cheesesquare:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

It demonstrates how to do this with the help of the design support library.

Comment: I think the demo you provide can solve my confusion, Thank you very much! You're very kind!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should go through Google's material design guide:

http://www.google.com.ua/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#introduction-principles

http://www.google.com.ua/design/

Then there are some libraries but none of them is complete ,this is one of the best for starting Material design on Github:

https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Comment: The **MaterialDesignLibrary**, I "Watched" it in Github before, It is useful. Thank you!